# What is the dual of a prism or an affine traversal?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, category-theory, lenses

A *prism* is an optic for focusing into coproduct types, while [*affine traversal*](http://oleg.fi/gists/posts/2017-03-20-affine-traversal.html) is a kind of optic which can focus at 0 of 1 element, i.e. `AffineTraversal s t a b` is isomorphic to `(s -> Maybe a, (s, b) -> t)`. As far as I know, we get an affine traversal when a lens is composed with a prism, provided an appropriate encoding of prisms is used.

I am interested in moving the `Maybe` in that (naive) formulation to the setter side as opposed to the getter side, so that I can have an optic that always extracts exactly one element, but may fail to put it back.

My use case is related to refinement types. Imagine that we have a type `A` and its refinement `B` (`B ⊆ A`). Then there is a prism `refined :: Prism' A B`: an `A` may or may not be a valid `B`, but each `B` can be `re` get into an `A`. Combining a `Lens' C A` with `refined`, we have an affine traversal. In the other direction, one may imagine an optic `unrefined` which is a little bit smarter than `re refined`: an `A` can be turned into `Just b`, if it is a valid `B`, or `Nothing`, if it is not. Now if we combine a `Lens' C B` with `unrefined`, we have our dual affine traversal: it can always obtain `A` from `C`, but putting back any old `A` may violate `C`'s invariant and yield `Nothing` instead of `Just c`. More complicated invariants may be ensured in a similar manner.

Interestingly, the [monocle](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle/blob/cdd129b7ac900c4226a610ed0b82937505713350/refined/shared/src/main/scala/monocle/refined/package.scala#L23) library for Scala offers prisms for refinement types, but nothing for the reverse direction.

I have hard times coming up with laws for these `(s -> a, b -> Maybe t)` and `(s -> a, (s, b) -> Maybe t)` gizmos, and I was wondering whether a more abstract formulation of optics is helpful.

I know that with profunctor lens, we have

```
type Lens s t a b = forall p. Strong p => p a b -> p s t
type Prism s t a b = forall p. Choice p => p a b -> p s t
type AffineTraversal s t a b = forall p. (Strong p, Choice p) => p a b -> p s t
```

which makes it really clear that a lens zooms into a product type, a prism zooms into a coproduct type, and an affine traversal has the ability to zoom into algebraic data type (products or coproducts, no less).

Is the answer connected to something like `Cochoice` or even `Costrong` (remove a product / coproduct from the profunctor instead of introducing it)? I wasn't able to restore the naive formulation from them, however...

Comment: I probably haven't fully understood your question, but I believe the dual of `Strong` is `Choice` and correspondingly the dual of `Lens` is `Prism`. ([Source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#t:Prism).) That makes the dual of `AffineTraversal`... `AffineTraversal`.

Comment: "dual"  was probably an unfortunate choice of wording from ne, then

Comment: You can "turn optics around" with `Re` to turn `Prisms a b s t` into the profunctor optic equivalent of `(s -> a, b -> Maybe t)`, see this blogpost http://oleg.fi/gists/posts/2017-04-18-glassery.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's half an answer, showing the correspondence between the `Cochoice` optic and `(s -> a, b -> Maybe t)`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

module P where

import Data.Profunctor
import Control.Monad

data P a b s t = P (s -> a) (b -> Maybe t)

instance Profunctor (P a b) where
  dimap f g (P u v) = P (u . f) (fmap g . v)

instance Cochoice (P a b) where
  unleft (P u v) = P (u . Left) (v >=> v') where
    v' (Left t) = Just t
    v' (Right _) = Nothing

type Coprism s t a b = forall p. Cochoice p => p a b -> p s t

type ACoprism s t a b = P a b a b -> P a b s t

fromCoprism :: ACoprism s t a b -> P a b s t
fromCoprism p = p (P id Just)

toCoprism :: P a a s t -> Coprism s t a a
toCoprism (P u v) = unleft . dimap f g where
  f (Left s) = u s
  f (Right a) = a
  g b = case v b of
    Nothing -> Right b
    Just t -> Left t
```

Comment: It is somewhat unsatisfying that a type-chainging version of `toCoprism` is not possible. based on http://oleg.fi/gists/posts/2017-04-18-glassery.html , the solution is to define `P` in terms of `reviewE` instead of `review` by replacing `Maybe` with `Either a`

Comment: I also tried to implement concrete and profunctor representations for some interesting lenses: https://gist.github.com/kris7t/b29519bee925b070d657e5f7c6a5650a , although I haven't checked yet whether the `from*`/`to*` pairs are indeed isomorphism. It seems that the "partial setter" (`Foo` in my gist) is obtained by a `(Strong p, Cochoice p)` constraint